# How can I watch an address on Windows and Android?

Tags: wallet, wallet.dat, android, watch-only

I want to be informed of transactions of my Bitcoin address on the Windows and the Android app. Can I use the same Bitcoin address on both? If yes, how can I backup the address on Windows and restore it on Android?

Comment: Quick note, blockchain.info lets you monitor transactions for a given bitcoin address without importing any private keys. It's under import/export "Watch Address"

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE. Please only ask about one topic per post: I've edited your question to refocus it on the second part, i.e. watching an address with two different apps. Your first question is answered for example here: [What's the difference between a wallet and an address?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/13281/5406), [What is the role of bitcoin wallets?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/21758/5406). Please feel free to edit this post if I didn't capture your intent for the second question. If you find your question about wallets not answered, please repost it as its own post.

Answer (score 2):

Just use bitcoind 
-walletnotify=    Execute command when a wallet transaction changes (%s in cmd is replaced by TxID)

in a script or for more details, access the bitcoind API via RPC  https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

Answer (score -1):

You can add and monitor addresses in http://blockonomics.co
It can be used on both desktop and mobile